# How to invoke managed bean action in rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, popup, richfaces

I need to confirm with the user if he or she are sure about delete his or her account.
For this I think a popup screen would be cool. But most browser block the popup windows.

So I was trying to do that with [popupPanel](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky).
But I'm guessing that would not be possible because I have a commandLink inside of it, here's what I'm doind so far :

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popup_delete_profile" modal="true" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('popup_delete_profile')}.hide()">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Aviso" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup_delete_profile')}.hide(); return false;">
            Close
            </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>


        <p>Are you sure ?</p>

        <h:commandLink value="Yes" action="#{userc.deleteUser}"></h:commandLink>

        <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup_delete_profile')}.hide(); return false;">
            No
        </h:outputLink>        

    </rich:popupPanel>
```

This is my manageBean:

```
    public void deleteUser(){
        try {
                eaoUser.delete(userb.getUser());
                // here I would like to refresh the popupPanel saying that was deleted with success and then logout

        } catch (Exception e) {
            view.errorMessage("ocorreu um erro, por favor tente novamente");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

```
public String deleteUser() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

}

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: So what is your question exactly? And why do you want to invalidate the user's session on click of the Yes link?

Answer (score 0):

There are two samples for your problem in the richFaces live demo

- [RichFaces 3.3](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=editDataTable&cid=47922)
- [RichFaces 4.0](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=dataTableEdit&skin=ruby)

In the RF 4 live demo, they include a sample of the Managed Bean.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @BalusC yes I have noticed that but the sample I posted was a dataTable using a popupPanel to edit/delete data, similar to his problem.

Comment: Ah right, sorry you was just not clear in explaining the concrete problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

How to invoke managed bean action in rich:popupPanel

```
   Add this code in your popUp.xhtml page

    Note:replace rich:popuppanal and use rich:modalPanel

    <a4j:commandLink styleClass="no-decor" execute="@this" render="@none"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.show()">
        <h:graphicImage value="/images/icon-delete.gif" />
        </a4j:commandLink>

        <rich:modalPanel id="confirmPane" width="282" height="70">
        Are you sure you want to delete the row?
        <button id="cancel"  onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide();" >
        <h:outputText value="cancel" escape="false" />
        </button>
        <button id="delete"  onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide();                  clickHiddenButton('officeForm:yesSubmit');return true;">
        <h:outputText value="yes" escape="false" />
        </button>
        <h:commandButton id="yesSubmit" style="visibility:hidden;"
        onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide()" action="deleteRecord" />
        </rich:modalPanel>
```